# AngularJS and jsFiddle not working - getting weird errors

Tags: angularjs, jsfiddle

So I am trying to get my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GeorgiAngelov/FtbSB/) to work but I get this error and a few others:

```
Error in event handler for 'undefined': Error calling method on NPObject. Error: Error calling method on NPObject.
    at chrome-extension://mkfokfffehpeedafpekjeddnmnjhmcmk/docstart.js:1:2117
    at Event.dispatchToListener (event_bindings:356:21)
    at Event.dispatch_ (event_bindings:342:27)
    at Event.dispatch (event_bindings:362:17)
    at miscellaneous_bindings:165:24
    at Event.dispatchToListener (event_bindings:356:21)
    at Event.dispatch_ (event_bindings:342:27)
    at Event.dispatch (event_bindings:362:17)
    at Object.chromeHidden.Port.dispatchOnMessage (miscellaneous_bindings:253:22)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what is causing the NPObject errors (see if [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8936795/uncaught-error-error-calling-method-on-npobject) helps), but when using ng-include with a hard-coded string, you need to quote it:

```
<div ng-repeat="question in questions" ng-include="'question'"></div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2J888/)