# "undefined" result using FileOpener Phonegap Android and failed to open video File?

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, cordova

i have downloaded plugin  [FileOpener](https://github.com/michalzubkowicz/FileOpener/tree/cordova-2.8.0)
   and added in m,y project like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"  dir="ltr">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,  user-scalable=no">
   <title>sample</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet"  href="css/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet"  href="css/adidas.css">
  <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/data_en.js"></script>
  <script src="js/data_sp.js"></script>
  <script src="js/adidas.js"></script>
  <script src="js/cordova.js"></script>
  <script src="js/video.js"></script>
  <script src="js/fileopener.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
 <div data-role="page" data-theme="a" class="my-page" id="video">
  <video id="video_player" src="#" controls="controls"></video> 
</div>
</body>
```

**in  js file**

```
    $(document).on('pagebeforeshow',"#video", function () {
   var xyz = document.getElementById('video_player');
    alert("values xyz:" + xyz);
     var x =  window.plugins.fileOpener.open("file:///android_asset/www/videos/1974.mp4");
  xyz.src =  window.plugins.fileOpener.open("file:///android_asset/www/balls/1970.png");

    alert("opener:" + x);
    window.plugins.videoPlayer.play(x);
    alert("xyz after src:" +  xyz);
});
```

[image: **firstalert**]
[image: second alert]
[image: third alert]
i am failed to open any video file/ images from assets/www/videos/abcd.mp4   and similar for images

now everything is working fine but this is alert when trying to hit play button : 
[image]

Comment: have you added all the java file in src folder in android and have you added the plugin in your config.xml file?

Comment: And fileOpener plugin is used to open all your images, video in systems application like mx player, imageViewer not in your cordova webpage

Comment: yes i have added all java files and added plugin in config.xml as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en"  dir="ltr">
 <head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,  user-scalable=no">
<title>sample</title>
<script src="js/cordova.js"></script>
<script src="js/video.js"></script>
<script src="js/fileopener.js"></script>
<script src="js/ADD_ANY_JQUERY.MIN.JS"></script>
<script>
   function openFile(filePath)
  {
     window.plugins.fileOpener.open(filePath);
  }
</script
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page" data-theme="a" class="my-page" id="video">
<img src="img/b_img1.png" onclick="openFile('file:///android_asset/www/videos/1974.mp4')"/>
</div>
</body>
```

**Edited**
Fileopener.js will be like this:

```
cordova.define("cordova/plugin/fileopener",
  function(require, exports, module) {
    var exec = require("cordova/exec");
    var FileOpener = function () {};

FileOpener.prototype.open = function(url) {
    exec(null, null, "FileOpener", "openFile", [url]);
};

FileOpener.prototype.setTAG = function(tag) {
    exec(null, null, "FileOpener", "setTAG", [tag]);
};
var fileOpener = new FileOpener();
    module.exports = fileOpener;

});
/**
 * Load Plugin
 */
if (!window.plugins) {
    window.plugins = {};
}
if (!window.plugins.fileOpener) {
    window.plugins.fileOpener = cordova.require("cordova/plugin/fileopener");
}
```

"js/ADD_ANY_JQUERY.MIN.JS" 
 in this line add a any jquery.min.js

Lastly check that **Cordova.js** folder is in your js folder of your application.. And let me know if it is not working what's your logcat saying...

Comment: i have added a\ll files correctly jquery , cordova.jquery-mobile and i m using cordova 2.9.0 and min-sdk version is 8 because my device supports android 2.2   right now added your code its displaying image but clicking on image showing nothing no video ....... and logcat is:   01-06 19:36:53.132: D/PluginManager(9420): exec() call to unknown plugin: FileOpener
01-06 19:36:53.202: D/CordovaLog(9420): file:///android_asset/www/js/fileopener.js: Line 20 : Class not found
01-06 19:36:53.202: I/Web Console(9420): Class not found at file:///android_asset/www/js/fileopener.js:20

Comment: This is because it is not fonding any codrova.js file in your apllication. Make sure that you have cordova-2.9.0.js in our js folder and the script like this js/cordova-2.9.0.js

Comment: i have added cordova-2.9.0.js from cordova website and its already saved in  js folder is there any problem because i m using cordova2.9.0 and fileopener of cordova 2.8.0

Comment: i have edited my questions and added how i add all js src files

Comment: In my answer i have used fileopener plugin. First add fileopener plugin in your src and config.xml file then let me know.

Comment: yes i have added fileOpener plugin in my src and config.xml but still getting same alert "Sorry This video cannot be played"  and when i m trying to open image then it shows confirmation dialog whether to open image from  ASTRO IMAGE VIEWER OR GALLERY clicking on imageviewer shows alert "There is either an error in the file type or it is an incomplatible file type"

Comment: logcat:  09-27 03:38:07.830: D/CordovaLog(11823): file:///android_asset/www/js/adidas/fileopener.js: Line 22 : Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'exec'
09-27 03:38:07.830: E/Web Console(11823): Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'exec':22

Comment: about an hour ago you said "still getting same alert "Sorry This video cannot be played" and when i m trying to open image then it shows confirmation dialog whether to open image from ASTRO IMAGE VIEWER OR GALLERY clicking on imageviewer shows alert "There is either an error in the file type or it is an incomplatible file type"" this means your plugin is working fine.... try to play other video files rather than it..

Comment: but as well as when i m checking my logcat there is also an error due to which i m failed to open an image and getting Sorry This video cannot be played"  and this is the same error of Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'exec':22  at fileopener.js

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38099/discussion-between-user1668447-and-andru)

Answer (score 1):

i was using cordova 2.9.0 , jquery 1.9.1 ,jqm-1.3.2  and android-sdk-version:14      after adding code  i was getting error:**logcat is**:

```
01-06 19:36:53.132: D/PluginManager(9420): exec() call to unknown plugin: FileOpener 
 01-06 19:36:53.202: D/CordovaLog(9420): file:///android_asset/www/js/fileopener.js: Line 20 : Class not found     
01-06 19:36:53.202: I/Web Console(9420): Class not found at file:///android_asset/www/js/fileopener.js:20
```

the solution of this problem is i have done mistake in config.xml and in plugin.xml:
**config.xml**  replace this:

```
 <feature name="videoplayer">
        <param name="android-package" value= "com.adidas.football.app.videoPlayer.VideoPlayer"/>
    </feature>
```

with:

```
  <feature name="VideoPlayer">
        <param name="android-package" value= "com.adidas.football.app.videoPlayer.VideoPlayer"/>
    </feature>
```

**plugin.xml** replace this:

```
<plugin name="videoplayer" value= "com.adidas.football.app.videoPlayer.VideoPlayer"/>
```

with:

```
 <plugin name="VideoPlayer" value= "com.adidas.football.app.videoPlayer.VideoPlayer"/>
```

a minor mistake of CAPITAL LETTER but it removes all error and finally i have no error except last one alert which i added in my  edited question "**cannot play video"**