# Cordova - Select a file to upload using navigator.camera

Tags: android, cordova

Can I use navigator.camera.getPicture() in cordova api to select a pdf from device? my code is

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(fileUploadSuccess,fileUploadFail,
            {sourceType:navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY, 
            destinationType:navigator.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
            quality:50,mediaType:navigator.camera.MediaType.ALLMEDIA});
```

the code opens device gallery but i can see only image files. Do I need to change any options? Is there any alternative if I can't use camera.getPicture() method? I am using cordova as this is a hybrid app.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can.
At least on Android with camera plugin v4.0.3

I'm using the folowing code

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, {
    sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
    mediaType:navigator.camera.MediaType.ALLMEDIA,
    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI
});
```

And it let me select any files : pdf, docx...

It returns the file Uri, even if you use DATA_URL as the destinationType.

Answer (score 1):

No, You need to Use FileOpener Plugin for that Purpose...

I used this Link :-  https://github.com/markeeftb/FileOpener

It also has a suggestion for its Use. This works For Me..

Comment: thanks @Akshay. can this plugin be used in a hybrid app - to be used in Android, Apple, Windows phone devices?

Comment: this plugin is for opening files, not for selecting them

Comment: No, its only For android...But I think This May Help...https://github.com/pwlin/cordova-plugin-file-opener2

Comment: For selecting item, you should use  filechooser plugin : https://github.com/cdibened/filechooser

Answer (score 0):

You cann't open file using getPicture(), you can you file opener :

https://github.com/pwlin/cordova-plugin-file-opener2

you can refer this also:
   [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17873452/how-to-open-a-pdf-file-using-jquery-and-phonegap-in-android)

Comment: He wants to select a file (to upload it for exemple), not to show it like file-opener2 does.