# ZeroClipBoard forceHandCursor? Global config not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, zeroclipboard

Hi I just started using ZeroClipBoard, so I am still acclimating myself with it. I have it working however I can not for the life of me get the hand cursor icon on hover of the elements. I am also getting an error in the console everytime i hover a clip element: Uncaught Error: Error calling method on NPObject.

**Here is a link to the project: http://git-cheatsheet.com/**

**Here is my code:**

```
ZeroClipboard.config({ forceHandCursor: true });
var client = new ZeroClipboard( gitSnip );

    client.on( "ready", function( readyEvent ) {
    client.on( "copy", function (event) {
      var clipboard = event.clipboardData;
      clipboard.setData( "text/plain" );
    });

    client.on( "aftercopy", function( event ) {

        $(".overlay").fadeIn().addClass('active');
        setTimeout(function(){
            $(".overlay").fadeOut().removeClass('active');
        },1200);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To customise the button with CSS you can't use the usual pseudo-classes of :hover or :active you have to use the zeroclipboard sub-classes: .zeroclipboard-is-hover and .zeroclipboard-is-active . This is because you have the clear Flash element over the top which is blocking direct access to the underlying button.

## d_clip_button.zeroclipboard-is-hover { background-color:#eee; }

## d_clip_button.zeroclipboard-is-active { background-color:#aaa; }

See the zeroclipboard documentation in more detail under CSS Effects at https://github.com/zeroclipboard/zeroclipboard/blob/master/docs/instructions.md

As to your error in the console check out this answer [Uncaught Error: Error calling method on NPObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8936795/uncaught-error-error-calling-method-on-npobject)

Answer (score 1):

This css worked for me with ZeroClipboard v2.1.6 :

```
 .zeroclipboard-is-hover { cursor:pointer; }
```