# The Flash player doesn't work in browsers on the Browserstack anymore?

Tags: flash, firefox, selenium-webdriver, browserstack

I am working on automation tests for a website and this website uses Flash player on some pages. I run my test locally and all looks smooth, but when I try to run my test on Browserstack, if the test tries to interact with site's functionality that uses Flash player - it doesn't work. There is an error in the browser's console - 
`Error: Error calling method on NPObject!`

For tests, I use Firefox browser (67.0) on Windows 10.

There is my config for Firefox profile:

```
FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
firefoxProfile.setPreference("plugin.state.flash", 2);
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
capabilities.setCapability("marionette",true);
capabilities.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, firefoxProfile);
```

And there is config for Browserstack

```
  "capabilities": {
    "build": "My ATS",
    "name": "My Automation tests 1.00",
    "browserstack.debug": true,
    "acceptSslCerts": true,
    "browserstack.console": "errors"
  },
  "environments": {
    "default": {
      "os": "Windows",
      "os_version": "10",
      "browser": "Firefox",
      "browser_version": "67.0",
      "resolution": "1920x1080"
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, I found a problem and it is not Flash player.

The thing is that my website under test tries to interact with a webcam and microphone, but there is no virtual or emulated device available in Browserstack session for the webcam.

Answer (score 1):

You may review the following online resources for the error -

- **[Error calling method on NPObject!](https://www.wrichards.com/blog/2009/02/error-calling-method-on-npobject/)**
- **[error-calling-method-on-npobject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8936795/uncaught-error-error-calling-method-on-npobject)**

I executed the test on Firefox using the capabilities you have mentioned and it worked fine for me!

Comment: I think, I found a problem and it is not Flash player.
The thing is that my website under test tries to interact with a webcam and microphone, but there is no virtual or emulated device available in Browserstack session for the webcam.

Answer (score 0):

You can review this FAQ for the device camera: https://www.browserstack.com/question/658.

Comment: This FAQ for mobile devices, in my case - I am trying to use the webcam from the desktop web browser.